# ORDER BY multiple case

Tags: mysql

[image]

Hi, how to sort this data based on version of windows using **mysql** ya? I need to become like this :

WINDOWS 2000
WINDOWS 7 HOME PREMIUM
WINDOWS 7 PROFESSIONAL
WINDOWS 7 ULTIMATE
WINDOWS 8
WINDOWS 8 PRO
WINDOWS 8.1
WINDOWS 10 HOME
WINDOWS 10 PRO

Please guide me. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you need to manage another field of launch date or sort order. Set that manually and then order by that field will work.

Comment: I second @NaveedRamzan opinion. It's much better in terms of future data addition.

Comment: Consider improving the way your data is stored. In the mean time, something like `ORDER SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_column,' ',2),' ',-1)` will suffice.

Answer (score -1):

> @Que check this ...

```
  select * from tablename order by FIELD(WINDOWS_TYPE , 'WINDOWS 2000', 'WINDOWS 7 HOME PREMIUM', 'WINDOWS 7 PROFESSIONAL', 'WINDOWS 7 ULTIMATE','WINDOWS 8','WINDOWS 8 PRO','WINDOWS 8.1','WINDOWS 10 HOME','WINDOWS 10 PRO') desc
```

Comment: Absolute genius.